# Trying to install Rimble from ConsenSys but run into errors. "Could not resolve dependency: react@"^16.9.0, from rimble-ui@0.14.0" What should I do?

Tags: reactjs

Used `npm install --save rimble-ui styled-components` to try to install rimble but got an error:

```
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.9.0" from rimble-ui@0.14.0 



npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Any ideas what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

This is a dependency issue. The library you are using has as a dependency an older version of React(16.9.0 while you have installed version 17.0.2). If you want to use that library you have to uninstall the current version of react:

`npm uninstall react`

And then install the required version:

`npm install react@16.9.0`